# error reversed() :list is not callable

Tags: python, list, typeerror

```
def dictrev():
    prompt = "Enter the key and value of a dictionary like this: 'key:value':"
    list = [];list_rev = [];i = 0
    while True:
        element = raw_input(prompt).strip().split(':')
        if element == ['.']:
            break
        list.append([]);list_rev.append([])
        print element
        print list(reversed(element))
        list[i] = element
        list_rev[i] = list(reversed(element))  
        i += 1
    print 'The dictionary you input is:'
    print dict((list))
    print '\nThe dictionary whose key and value are reversed is:'
    print dict((list_rev))

dictrev()
```

This is the code of the question in *Core Python Programming* 7-7.

However, when I run the program, I got a **TypeError: 'list' object is not callable** in the code

`print list(reversed(element))`

What I have done are as follows:

1. search the 'list is not callable' topic in Stackoverflow and google, but I don't get the method;
2. goole the method of list() and reversed(), but I don't think there is anything wrong with my code
3. print the variable element, element_reversed and the type of element.
4. take the code alone in another program like this:

`l = ['a','b']`

`print l`

`print list(reversed(l))`

there is nothing wrong like 'list object is not callable.' I am puzzled!!!

I have done what I can do to solve this problem. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Don't assign variables to built-in functions.

Comment: You overwrote `list`, working with it on the line right before the error. What did you think would happen? Also, your code is far from standard Python. I suggest you take a look at some tutorials.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
list = []
```

You overrode the built in type `list`

Comment: SO really confuses me sometimes with the upvotes / downvotes... I expected to be downvoted to hell for answering something that's been answered only 293933 times and is a deff dupe, but nope 6 upvotes because I was too lazy to find the canonical dupe lol.

Comment: Yeah good stuff man, another upvote for you're perfect answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm embarrassed about most of my highly-upvoted answers. It's a mystery to me too.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have got the point and realized that this is such a silly question.